# I want an exact value of Pi

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Use 1, 2, 2, 2 (Each number used exactly once) to form π.
I want an exact value of π, not any approximation.

Available operators:

> + - * / ( ) ^ !
>   You can use any one of them for any times.

Hint:

> Think about a special feature of the "!".

Comment: MathJax is very slow here.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't recommend using MathJax unless it's necessary for things like fractions - for some people, it takes a while to load. (Here, you could easily just use the π character rather than switching to MathJax.)

Comment: *I want an exact value of π, not any approximation* - I wholeheartedly endorse this message.

Comment: Instead of the factorial do you mean the gamma function? It seems that the only answer provided erroneously uses the factorial rather than the gamma function (the factorial is only defined for positive integers).

Comment: Well, not exact, but I remember it to 19 digits: 3.141592653589793238

Answer (score 15):

It is

> $(2 \times (\frac{1}{2})!)^2$

This [video](https://youtu.be/QhDDpSju3uY) tells why.

Comment: By my calculations, this adds up to 4 times domain error squared.

Comment: Factorial is only defined for positive integers. This answer clearly means to use the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) _(one of - but not the only - way to extend factorials to the complex numbers)_, but that was not one of the allowed functions in the question...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Stating that `!` is a gamma function in the question would give away the answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft But we all know it's only possible if factorial is interpreted as gamma function - which is the only point of this question...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The gamma function is the *standard* way to extend factorials to the complex numbers. If you write $\alpha!$ for $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{N}$ in mathematics, this is assumed to mean $\Gamma(\alpha+1)$. See for example [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%21) and my experience as a mathematician in a field where gamma functions are used all over the place.

Comment: As further evidence, it works on my TI calculator.

Comment: @Randal'Thor If the puzzle had said "you can use addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation and the gamma function", I would agree that this is a nice puzzle indeed, and it would be perfectly fine to use whatever notation to arrive at the solution. Instead OP told us to use the "exclamation point operator", which in the context of make-a-number puzzles means "factorial" and is strictly integer-only. So while the answer is very clever and highlights an interesting mathematical factoid, the phrasing of the puzzle sadly puts it in the XKCD-169 category.

Comment: @Bass I disagree. Saying "the gamma function" explicitly would make the puzzle trivial and pointless. The exclamation point is *not* strictly integer-only in mathematics, and using it in this way makes for a very clever puzzle - kudos to the OP. If you don't believe me, all I can do is point to the evidence in my previous comment. I work with factorials and gamma functions every day, and use $\alpha!$ completely interchangeably with $\Gamma(\alpha+1)$.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I agree it may be a clever puzzle *for you*. For someone who **doesn't** work with gamma functions all day, this puzzle depends on an obscure redefinition of a symbol. It's pretty much unsolvable unless you explicitly go out of your way to find lateral-thinking solutions along the lines of "maybe, when OP says ^, they mean the bitwise XOR" or "I'll just use the parens to make a *choose* function". Those particular uses aren't any less common than "! for gamma", and still it definitely would be frowned upon if the intended solution depended on either of them.

Comment: @Bass It's not some deeply arcane thing: I mentioned my familiarity with these functions only to show that I know what I'm talking about. I also mentioned [Wolfram Alpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%21) for $\frac{1}{2}!$. Unlike your analogies, this is not re-interpreting an existing symbol to mean something unexpected: it's *the standard definition* of the factorial function applied to non-integers. The answer to this question is obvious once you have the right 'aha', and obviously *not* solvable in another way because $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: @Randal'Thor My phone's calculator (Android 9) says "Domain error", my computer's (OSX 10.14) says "Not a Number". Wikipedia's [list of mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) doesn't mention that use, and neither does the [page about the exclamation point itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclamation_mark). The page for [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) explicitly states that the equality applies to positive integers, and never uses the notation to mean the gamma function. So, maybe a little arcane, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Another mathematician here. I agree with Rand that _among mathematicians_ it's absolutely standard to allow the domain of ! to include non-integers. But I agree with Bass that _for everyone else_ it's really obscure. It feels to me like this puzzle is XKCD169-ish for non-mathematicians -- and _too easy_ for mathematicians. (I'd have solved this as soon as I saw the question if athin hadn't got there first. I expect Rand would have too.)