# Make $\pi$ using 2 0 2 0 in this order

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

How can you make $\pi$ using 2, 0, 2, 0 in this order?

Allowed operations: 
+, -, x, ÷, ! (factorial), exponentiation, parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since

> $\left(\frac12\right)!=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$ and $\left(-\frac12\right)!=\sqrt\pi$

we have

> $(-2^{-0!})!^2+0=\pi$.

I'm sure I remember a recent puzzle based on the same idea, but I'm failing to find it. There was

> some heated disagreement in the comments about whether it's reasonable to have a puzzle that requires solvers to know that the factorial function is defined for values that aren't nonnegative integers (and I think some people protested that it *isn't* and we should always use the gamma function instead when we want to allow non-integer arguments, though I don't think many mathematicians would agree with that). For what it's worth, I'm on the permissive side here: I think it's entirely reasonable. [EDITED to add:] Though, having now found the other question, I see that in comments there I took a different view. Perhaps I'm suffering from bias either out of annoyance before at someone else's having got to the question before me, or out of self-interest having solved this one :-).

Aha, found it:

> [I want an exact value of Pi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90669/i-want-an-exact-value-of-pi/)

I'm not sure whether this should be regarded as a duplicate of that one. It isn't the same question but it's clearly closely related.

Comment: right, I think it was for 2019, but the idea is very similar, well done!